# What are the pros and cons of rspec mocking versus other mocking frameworks?

Tags: ruby, rspec, frameworks, mocking, rspec-mocks

I have seen a lot of outdated podcasts that mention mocha as a gem I would want to install because it does mocking better then rspec. I have a feeling that the rspec developers have caught on to this and have improved their mocking since then. However, in the default `spec_helper.rb` file I see some commented out code stubs for three mocking frameworks

- `mocha`
- `flexmock`
- `rr`

Upvote to anyone who can give me a decent answer as far as pros and cons on at least one of these frameworks versus `rspec`'s own mocking framework.

I'll accept an answer if you can give me a break down on all three versus `rpsec`